# Scoring categories from web logs

Tags: cluster-computing, scoring, quantile

I am building a scorer for individual scoring for categories on a website.

**Input :** userid,  category

**Output :** user id, score_cat_1, score_cat_2 etc...

The score are given on 10.

My plan is to first count for each user how many clicks for each categories, then to divide the results in quantile (maybe a thousand), to finally use a cluster algorithm for each categories quantiles to clsuter them in 10 clusters, who will be ordered, and give the rate.

The idea is to group the quantiles who are close together in a same cluster and get a more interesting score than only saying "the 10% best clickers get a 10, the next 10% get a 9 etc...

**My problems are following:**

1- do you think it is a good idea? Is there more natural and accurate way to do it?

2- the cluster may be too small, and I can't guarantee the cardinal on each cluster.